# generalizations of determinant and trace

Tags: linear-algebra

There are $n$ symmetric polynomials in the eigenvalues of a square matrix. Two of these are the determinant and the trace, each of which have countless applications and interpretations in algebra and geometry.

What about the other symmetric polynomials? They are also similarity invariants, yet I've never seen them used or referenced. Are there any geometric interpretations, or applications, for these other invariants?

Comment: Of course, the invariant that collects all those together is the characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trace and the determinant are the most useful invariants because the trace is additive and the determinant is multiplicative. The other coefficients of the characteristic polynomial are neither. The determinant also has a clear geometric interpretation. In addition, all of the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of an operator $T$ can be computed from the traces of the operators $T^n$; this is one reason why it is not so surprising that traces of group elements in group representations carry a lot of information.

This is not to say that people never *use* the other invariants, although they don't tend to have special names. For example, my understanding is that the [Killing form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_form) in Lie theory, an important tool, was discovered by messing around with characteristic polynomials. And the construction underlying the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial, the [exterior algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra), is enormously useful.

Comment: Would like to add that the other coefficients do in fact have a fairly nice geometric interpretation. Remembering that the coefficients in the characteristic polynomial correspond with symmetric polynomials of the eigenvalues, and that the eigenvalues tell us how much the linear transformation "stretches" space, we can imagine for instance in 3D a unit "box" is transformed to give another with sides $\lambda_1$...$\lambda_2$. For instance, the determinant in this case corresponds to the volume (multiplication of all 3 eigenvalues), the trace is 1/4th the sum of edges (the "perimeter")...

Comment: ...And finally pairwise multiplication $\lambda_1\lambda_2+\lambda_2\lambda3+\lambda_1\lambda_3$ gives 1/2 the area. This is also equal to $a_{00}*a_{11}-a_{01}*a_{10}+a_{00}*a_{22}-a_{02}*a_{20}+a_{11}*a_{22}-a_{12}*a_{21}$ for a 3 by 3 matrix $A$. However, like you I'm not sure what kind of operation this preserves (by which I mean, for instance, the determinant preserves multiplication and the trace preserves addition).

Answer (score 2):

I think you  are thinking of the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial -the trace and the determinant are the "extremes". 
See eg 
http://alert.comule.com/?p=7741
and 
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33478/geometric-interpretation-of-characteristic-polynomial

Comment: I think the question can be seen as a duplicate then.